# CSS or JavaScript putting background color into only part of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I have so far and here is [the link](http://buk.io/@19924/3/654:0:90~654:0:175) to see it online.

```
p { line-height: 2; }
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

[image: Screen capture]

The goal is to wrap the quoted content like below (no border is necessary but I want the whole background including the space between lines to be colored)

I see that the picture isn't clear but I hope you can figure out the idea.

[image: Screen Capture (Goal)]

The current version only highlights the lines and the space between lines(due to line height being taller than 1) is not highlighted.

Is there any way to achieve this either in CSS or in JavaScript?

Comment: you could try to do that with css shapes, but it's [not a fully supported feature](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes)

Comment: Please include related HTML and CSS in the question

Comment: @Amit So it's not doable (or at least practically). Right?

Comment: @msk - You could elaborately calculate the shape surrounding your text, and then use some form of filled shape elements (SVG?), but that's not really practical either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to give the marked text a top and bottom padding.

```css
p {line-height:2}
mark {padding:.5em 0}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<mark>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</mark>
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks to your solution, now the site shows quote better. Please see it yourself. http://buk.io/@1400/13/2487:0:62~2487:0:220

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the span tag and set the background of that span so it will work like

```
<p>this is the dummy text without any background <span style='background:yellow'> This text with the background colour</span> this text have no background</p>
```

Comment: No, that's what the current version is doing and there is white color(background of the paragraph) is visible so that the space between lines is not highlighted. You will see two yellow lines instead one block of yellow.

Comment: @msk i have tested it will show the space with highlighted colour https://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/79z9065r/

Comment: Please set "line-height" bigger than 1. Thanks.